# How to load balance legacy application using nginx?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

We have a legacy application server. We need to scale up the server to increase the throughput.
 Can we use nginx to load balance? Legacy application listen to request on sockets/TCP.

Answer (score 1):

You could use nginx to load balance the application but the settings would depend on what kind of application it is and how it is working.

Based on the application, you may need to configure sticky sessions or some other settings to enable load balancing. Its difficult to say for sure without the complete details.

You can refer to the nginx documentation for [load balancers](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/) if you need any more details.